# Hardhat compile error "Expected a value of type HttpNetworkConfig"

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I'm attempting to follow the NFT tutorial [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/#write-contract).  I have set up the accounts on Alchemy and Metamask created the .sol file.  I have a .env file in root that looks like this:

```
API_URL = "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
PRIVATE_KEY = "your-metamask-private-key"
```

My hardhat config file looks like this:

```
/**

* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig

*/

require('dotenv').config();

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {

   solidity: {
      compilers: [
        {
          version: "0.5.7"
        },
        {
          version: "0.8.0"
        },
        {
          version: "0.6.12"
        }
      ]
    },

   defaultNetwork: "ropsten",

   networks: {

      hardhat: {},

      ropsten: {

         url: API_KEY,

         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]

      }

   },

}
```

However when I try to compile I keep getting this error:

> Invalid value
> {"url":"https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key","accounts":["0xyour-metamask-private-key"]}
> for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten - Expected a value of type
> HttpNetworkConfig.

I cannot seem to figure out why this is not a valid value for HttpNetworkConfig.  What I have where url is a string and accounts is an array would appear to comply with what is in the [documentation for network configs](https://hardhat.org/config/#networks-configuration).  It's a compile error so it would seem it cannot be a problem with the actual url or private key, but maybe I'm wrong about that. I willingly admit to being a noob here with only a cursory understanding of hardhat, solidity, and even js, etc. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the problem was with my private key.  Check carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working at `localhost:8545`.
I think the issue is the value of the assets and some accounts used in your context exist on the `mainnet`.
To solve this problem, you need to `hardfork` the `mainnet` to your local.

Please check this guide.
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting my `privateKey` to the `accounts` element.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a value for my `LIVE_PRIVATE_KEY` as I also had a `DEV_PRIVATE_KEY`